# Codename one javascript callback

Tags: javascript, codenameone

I am trying to display a consent page in my app. The page should be written in html so the app need to handle a button clicked event from browser. I tried to replicate [the example in blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-async-java-javascript-interop-api.html) (minus the jQuery part):

```
bc.addJSCallback(
    "document.getElementById('ACCEPT').addEventListener('click', function(){callback.onSuccess(true)})",
    res -> {
        System.out.println(res);
        dialog.dispose();
    }
);
```

The html looks like this:

```
<html>
<button id='ACCEPT'>Accept</button>
<button id='DECLINE'>Decline</button>
<script></script>
</html>
```

Nothing happened when the button was clicked. However, when the js expression was put in the `<script>` tag instead, `'callback' is not defined` was logged, suggesting that the js expression was not the cause.

I'd like to know which part went wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell but this HTML seems problematic to begin with. You are missing the body tag. Did you invoke `addJSCallback` after `onLoad` was invoked?

Comment: Maybe not I'll need to double check for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to the original question, it seems that the problem can be solved quite easily, and more data than simple `click` event can be passed as well.

---

Method 1:

Use a `<form>` or `<a>` to redirect the `BrowserComponent` to any page, and listen to 
navigation event, like

```
bc.addBrowserNavigationCallback(url -> {
    if (url.equals(initialPath)) { 
        return true; //Show the first page, but do no subsequent redirection
    }
    //Do something here with data encoded in url
});
```

Form data can be obtained as explained in [this link](https://code.lengstorf.com/get-form-values-as-json/).

---

Method 2:

Register a javascript object either as `onclick` of a button, or as a `function` that is called from javascript, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html#execute-int-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-com.codename1.util.SuccessCallback-).

```
bc.addWebEventListener(BrowserComponent.onLoad, evt -> {
    bc.execute("window.cb = json => {callback.onSuccess(json);};", json -> {
        //Do something with the data here (a json in this case)
    });
});
```

... and in javascript

```
const handleFormSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = formToJSON(form.elements); //Refer to link above
  const json = JSON.stringify(data);
  //const d = btoa(json); Does not work with unicode character
  cb(json);
};
const form = document.getElementsByName('formmm')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```

---

A few afterthought:

1. `WebEventListener` cannot be used with `BrowserNavigationCallback`
2. Passing json as base64 string is hard, see [Unicode Problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem)
3. While `encodeUrl()` is public (in `Util`), the inverse function is private in [BrowserComponent](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.java). This complicates passing js object as url
4. In Method 2 use `bc.addJsCallback` instead of `execute` to callback more than once

---

Hope this help someone