# Codename One - how to create webview communicate with native (iOS)

Tags: ios, codenameone

I am creating an mobile app which UI must be in html/reactjs and business logic must be in Java. Codename One is good option but its UI is Swing alike, so I am thinking can I load the local html onto the webview and let it communicates with the native code (Java) in Codename One?

I found this API [BrowserComponent](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html), I am going to attach the RESTful request and response in the browser window object, and use it to communicate via BrowserComponent API.

From native code (Java) to execute Javascript in webview, I found this [API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html#execute-java.lang.String-com.codename1.util.SuccessCallback-), but from webview to execute native code (Java), is there a way to do so?

Comment: Found this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676540/codename-one-javascript-callback, and the method 2 described inside is quite promising as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a navigation listener and then navigate to a well known URI which you can then map to what you want. See [addBrowserNavigationCallback](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html#addBrowserNavigationCallback-com.codename1.ui.events.BrowserNavigationCallback-). With that you can write code in the callback such as:

```
bc.addBrowserNavigationCallback(url -> {
      switch(url) {
          case "method1://invoke": 
              callSerially(() -> method1()); 
              return false;
          case "method2://invoke": 
              callSerially(() -> method2()); 
              return false;
      }
      return true;
});
```

You can pass arguments in the call which will make this code a but more complex but the gist is the same.

Notice that `callSerially` is essential here since this method exposes the browser navigation thread and blocks it. You shouldn't grab that thread.